# How to build every project in a solution by using msbuild.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Is there a possibility to build every project within a solution by using msbuild in the command line? I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

*This will not answer your exact question, but may be the solution that works for you:*

You can use the CLI of Visual Studio itself to have a very comfortable interface to build your solutions and projects. For example

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe \
[path to sln-file] /rebuild release
```

or to build just one project:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe \
[path to sln-file] /rebuild release /project [project name]
```